# Mixed parameter types for machine learning

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression

I wish to fit a logistic regression model with a set of parameters. The parameters that I have include three distinct types of data:

- Binary data [0,1]
- Categorical data which has been encoded to integers [0,1,2,3,...]
- Continuous data

I have two questions regarding pre-processing the parameter data before fitting a regression model:

1. For the categorical data, I've seen two ways to handle this. The first method is to use a one hot encoder, thus giving a new parameter for each category. The second method, is to just encode the categories with integers within a single parameter variable [0,1,2,3,4,...]. I understand that using a one hot encoder creates more parameters and therefore increases the risk of over-fitting the model; however, other than that, are there any reasons to prefer one method over the other?
2. I would like to normalize the parameter data to account for the large differences between the continuous and binary data. Is it generally acceptable to normalize the binary and categorical data? Should I normalize the categorical and the continuous parameters but not the binary parameters or can I just normalize all the parameter data types.

I realize I could fit this data with a random forest model and not have to worry much about pre-processing, but I'm curious how this applies with a regression type model.

Thank you in advance for your time and consideration.

Comment: did you look at [log-reg scikit learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_iris_logistic.html)

Comment: @InkSlob. Thanks for the response. I have seen that logistic regression example; however, in that particular example you linked to they only take two of the parameters from the iris data set which happen to be both continuous data. I'm interested in using mixed parameter types.

Comment: Oh sorry missed that part.  Have you considered LDA or QDA?  I've used LDA for something kind of similar.